# greasemonkey script running without timeout?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a very simple Greasemonkey script I created which should send out two messages to the console, the first right away and the second after a pause. For some reason they are both going right away without the pause... what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
console.log('first message');
setTimeout(function(){console.log('second message');},300000);
console.log('third message');
setTimeout(function(){console.log('fourth message');},300000);
document.getElementById('button').click();
```

Comment: The code that you posted works as is.  You'll need to post a larger sample of code -- something that doesn't work.

Comment: updated with the full script thank you

Comment: Assuming that button you click navigates away from the page, the `setTimeout` never has a chance to run.

Comment: Post enough information for us to duplicate the problem. Your current code works as expected.

Comment: Jeremy - why doesnt the the setTimeout have a chance to run? The button click does navigate away from the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the intent of your code is to do this:

```
* display a message (#1)
* wait 5 minutes and display a message (#2)
* display a message (#3)
* wait 5 minutes and display a message (#4)
* click a button and navigate away.
```

However, the setTimeout() function is asynchronous: it does NOT pause execution of the rest of the script until it completes, but rather starts a separate execution thread that will perform the action after the specified delay, while the primary program thread continues.<sup>1</sup>

Your function as written will actually take the following steps:

```
* display a message (#1).
* start a timer.
* display a message (#3).
* start a timer.
* Navigate to a new page.
```

All of those steps happen in very rapid succession.

Once a timer expires, it will cause a message to be printed.  Unfortunately, navigating to a new page kills your current execution context, which aborts your timers before they ever trigger.  If you didn't have that "navigate away" step, the code would run like this:

```
* display a message (#1).
* start a timer.
* display a message (#3).
* start a timer.
* (5 minutes pass.)
* first timer expires, displaying a message (#2)
* second timer expires, displaying a message (#4).
```

(Note, by the way, that both your timers are running down simultaneously; only 5 minutes total will go by, not 5 for the first and then 5 more for the second.)

If you want your button click to only happen after all of your other messages have displayed, you should put the button click on a timer call too:

```
setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('button').click();}, 300000);
```

<sup>1: this is an oversimplification to make the point of what's going on clearer.  For a much more precise explanation of JavaScript timers, see http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/ .</sup>

Comment: THANK YOU! I appreciate your clear explanation on why it wasn't working and why your proposed solution would work. I tried out your final line of code and it did exactly what I was looking for it to do. Much appreciated!